# Error While Performing NLTK on Spark RDD using spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, nltk

I have set pyspark_python as python3 and I want to perform NLTK on Spark RDD.
But while performing NLTK it's shown below Error.

```
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py", line 1881, in <listcomp>
if form.endswith(old)
TypeError: endswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str
```

It works well when I'm running spark application on HDP Cluster, but doesn't work on local system spark-submit.

Comment: can post code which creates `form` and `old` variable ?

Answer (score 1):

looks like `old` is of type `str`

`old.encode()` will convert it to bytes

try

```
if form.endswith(old.encode())
```

In Python 3, there's no implicit conversion between `unicode(str)` objects and `bytes` objects. If you know the encoding of the output, you can `.decode()` it to get a string, or you can turn the `\n` you want to add to bytes with `"\n".encode('ascii')`

So where you need to convert str to bytes use `.encode()`
and where you need to convert byes to str use `.decode()`

Comment: I'm performing NLTK on Spark RDD using following code 

`def lemma(x):`

 'import nltk`

'nltk.download('wordnet')`


`from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer`

`lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()`

`return lemmatizer.lemmatize(x)`


`data = sc.textFile(hdfs_src_dir, use_unicode=False)`

`lem_words = data.map(lemma)`

I have applied this solution in the NLTK library file, but now it's giving following Error.

`TypeError: can't concat str to bytes`

Comment: why there is no `old` anywhere in your code ? @AchyutVyas

Comment: It's a part of the NLTK library.